# Can the Smart-Vercauteren Homomorphic Encryption be implemented as a practical fully homomorphic encryption scheme?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Smart and Vercauteren proposed [a homomorphic encryption scheme (PKC 2010)](http://math.leidenuniv.nl/~dfreeman/smart.pdf) following Gentry's principles. ​ Though their scheme can achieve fully homomorphism theoretically, they admitted that "for practical values of n our scheme cannot be made fully homomorphic" (p. 16).

However, perhaps the <s>only</s> (see update 1 below) public fully (not somewhat) homomorphic encryption implementation [libScarab](https://github.com/hcrypt-project/libScarab), is claimed to be using the SV scheme. ​ The authors of that library also have a paper ["POSTER: An Implementation of the Fully Homomorphic Smart-Vercauteren Crypto-System" (CCS'11)](http://avierfjard.com/PDFs/Cryptography/PGP/Open%20Source%20Cryptography/An%20Implementation%20of%20the%20Fully%20Homomorphic.pdf) about their implementation.

There are several parameters chosen differently in the latter paper
from the original paper, maybe for achieving full homomorphism. But they did not explain the security of their choices, and I cannot figure out it by myself.

So my question is, can libScarab be viewed as a serious secure FHE implementation?

---

Update 1 (18 Nov 2015)

I've found there are two other public fully homomorphic encryption (including bootstrapping) libraries ([HELib](https://github.com/shaih/HElib) and [FHEW](https://github.com/lducas/FHEW)) released by illustrious cryptologists Shai Halevi / Victor Shoup and Leo Ducas / Daniele Micciancio. Both are slower than libScarab, but I think they supply more security.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SV scheme made some significant simplifications that turned out to hurt security.  Specifically, it's known how to break the scheme in subexponential time (roughly $2^{n^{2/3}}$) in the dimension $n$ of the lattice defined by the public key.  Moreover, it's known that the scheme can be broken in *polynomial time* by a quantum computer.  In short, the reason is that the SV scheme has an ad-hoc method of key generation, which tends to produce "weak" ideals that can be attacked more efficiently than arbitrary ideals.  See [this paper](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/logunit.pdf) for further details.

Comment: In SV, $N$ defined as $N = 2^n$. So the attack is $2^{N^{2/3}}$ or $2^{n^{2/3}}$

Answer (score 0):

If we refer to the original SV paper we'll find that they compute the security level (although it is assumed to be based on Gentry original work, and without taking their changes into consideration) so for certain values of parameters we can figure out the security level.  However, what is really weird is the work that implemented their model, they changed the parameters in a way that, in my opinion, degrades the security into very weak model ($2^{25}$) bit security. Also, I tried to change the parameters myself from the source file and I was surprised how this doesn't affect the keygen time and encryption time (the time should increase as the security parameters increase), but it gives wrong output values.

Comment: What was the parameters?

Comment: If you look to the header files you'll find the following values:               N 8
MU 4
LOG_NU 384
 S1 8
S2 5 . These parameters give 34 RSA bit security, which is very weak and can't be used.

Comment: This is the default values. There the parameters are, AFAIK, B_{2,N} not B_{2,\infty}.

Comment: Can you clarify please ? Yes these are the default values, I am trying to change them to reach certain security level

Comment: It seems, impractical. I was trying to do so, but gave up. 
In the original article, the depth is so small for the recrypt for practical implementation, they reach "This corresponds to N ≥ 136422400 or thus n  27".

Comment: Agree, but I am not sure if the original work is impractical, or the implementation is , because if yo read their implementation they wrote shallower algorithm based on  calculating hamming weight. Thanks for sharing your experience it is good to know that I am not the only one who could not achieve any security level. I was doubting doing something wrong

Comment: From the article : "We were unable to generate keys for the parameter size of N = 2^12 , and smaller values of N key generation could take many hours"

Also, I've noticed that Large Message space is not working. I don't know why!